# What is this scene, where Akamatsu tells about his secret hiding place, a reference to?

Tags: jinsei

In *Jinsei* episode 11, Akamatsu tells the girls about his "Secret Place for Hiding his *Dirty Stuff*" and makes this face, with text written like this.

[image: 計画通り - Just As Keikaku]

I'm not sure what is this is a reference to. Can somebody explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Yagami Light's [infamous scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkT4vAJnJls#t=7s) from *Death Note.*

[image: All according to keikaku!] [image: Keikaku means plan.]

Comment: Yes. That would also explain the 'Secret Compartment' in his Drawer. Thankyou!